# I have error check manual corresponding mysql server version

Tags: java, mysql, api

Repository:

package com.apsilabs.meterwebapi.repository;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.apsilabs.meterwebapi.model.ActualsBlockLoad;
import com.apsilabs.meterwebapi.viewmodel.ActualsBlock;

@Repository
public interface ActualsBlockLoadRepository extends JpaRepository<ActualsBlockLoad, Long> {
    @Query(nativeQuery=true,value= "SELECT NEW com.apsilabs.meterwebapi.viewmodel.ActualsBlock(CONVERT(hour(rtc), CHAR(50)) as hours,CONVERT(date(rtc), CHAR(50)) as dates,CONVERT(IFNULL(avg(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_UNQUOTE(data),'$.\\\"1012270255\\\"')),0),CHAR(50)) as voltage) from actuals_block_load  group by hours,dates order by dates,hours")
    public List<ActualsBlock> getActualsBlockLoad();

}
```

I have an error: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.apsilabs.meterwebapi.viewmodel.ActualsBlock(CONVERT(hour(rtc), CHAR(50)) as hou' at line 1

New Class:

```
package com.apsilabs.meterwebapi.viewmodel;

public class ActualsBlock {
    private String hours;
    private String dates;
    private String voltage;

    public String getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(String hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    public String getDates() {
        return dates;
    }

    public void setDates(String dates) {
        this.dates = dates;
    }

    public String getVoltage() {
        return voltage;
    }

    public void setVoltage(String voltage) {
        this.voltage = voltage;
    }

    public ActualsBlock(String hours, String dates, String voltage) {
        super();
        this.hours = hours;
        this.dates = dates;
        this.voltage = voltage;
    }

    public ActualsBlock() {
        super();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used **nativeQuery=true** and this query is not native.

```
SELECT NEW com.apsilabs.meterwebapi.viewmodel.ActualsBlock(CONVERT(hour(rtc), CHAR(50)) as hours,CONVERT(date(rtc), CHAR(50)) as dates,CONVERT(IFNULL(avg(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_UNQUOTE(data),'$.\\\"1012270255\\\"')),0),CHAR(50)) as voltage) from actuals_block_load  group by hours,dates order by dates,hours.
```

Why you are uisng NEW com.apsilabs.meterwebapi.viewmodel.ActualsBlock(CONVERT.... if is is a native query

Comment: If I change the query as hibernate it get an error: ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.NameGenerator.generateColumnNames(NameGenerator.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]

Comment: why you are using NEW com.apsilabs.meterwebapi.viewmodel.ActualsBlock( in query

Comment: I don't have a column in the database so I use a new entity as NEW com.apsilabs.meterwebapi.viewmodel.ActualsBlockpackage

Comment: It won't work this way. remove NEW com.apsilabs.meterwebapi.viewmodel.ActualsBlock and try with other columns, it would work.

Comment: After removing NEW com.apsilabs.meterwebapi.viewmodel.ActualsBlock ,it got error:No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.apsilabs.meterwebapi.viewmodel.ActualsBlock]